# javascript how to single line change all items in array

Tags: javascript

I need to make small change in an array, converting `item` in `{data:item, data_form:null}`

This is the cleanest way I can do it.

```
app.mydata = [];
api_data.forEach(item => app.mydata.push({data:item, data_form:null}));
```

Is there a single line way to do this? Maybe with `map()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` to bind `item` to `{data: item, data_form: null}` as follows.

```
const result = api_data.map((item) => ({
  data: item,
  data_form: null
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would do it.

```
app.mydata = api_data.map(item =>({data:item, data_form:null}));
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), but here's a shorter version:

```
app.mydata = api_data.map(data => ({ data, data_form: null }));
```